# Get wrong answer when doing MLE on gamma parameters

Tags: r, mle

I first want to sample 100 gamma distributed numbers where shape = 2 and scale = 1/2. I wrote down the log-likelyhood function and negated it since I'm using a minimization tool to maximize. I also tried using `optim` but to no avail. both `optim` and `nlm` gave me different answers. This is my code thus far:

```
N = 100
shape = 2     
scale = 1/2   
Data <- rgamma(SampSize, shape, scale)

LogL = function (x){
  k     = x[1]
  gamma = x[2]
  (-1)*(N*x[1]*log(x[2])+(x[1]-1)*sum(log(Data))-x[2]*sum(Data))   
}
nlm(LogL,c(1.5,1))
```

Comment: That worked, endless thanks! However, can you explain why my method does not work? EDIT: indeed I realised that afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

```
logL <- function (x) -sum(dgamma(Data, x[1], x[2], log = TRUE))

N = 100
shape = 2     
scale = 1/2   
Data <- rgamma(N, shape, scale)

optim(c(1.5, 1), logL)$par
nlm(logL, c(1.5, 1))$estimate
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask, once I use nlm, how can I access these estimator values? Where are they stored?